# Calculating the coefficients in a double Laurent series

Tags: series-expansion, coefficients

I am interested in calculating the coefficients in the Laurent series of the following Hankel function

$H_{0}^{(1)}(\sqrt{(3+x-y)(3+1/x-1/y)})$

I am familiar with the Coefficient command and its extensions (e.g. SeriesCoefficient and CoefficientList). However, a simple application of this won't evaluate e.g.

```
SeriesCoefficient[HankelH1[0,Sqrt[(3+x-y)(3+1/x-1/y)]],{x,0,2},{y,0,-2}]
```

Can someone please help me out? I'm aware that I could change this into a 2d Fourier series but there's no efficient way for calculating 2d Fourier coefficients without resorting to integration, that I'm aware of.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `Series[HankelH1[0, Sqrt[(3 + x - y) (3 + 1/x - 1/y)]], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 
   0, -2}] // FullSimplify` ?